# How can I resize the parent control from a child control's resize event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resize

Is there any good way to resize, for example the form height when a child control (for example a panel) size changes?

For example. Suppose a `Form` with a child panel inside. The panel has `DockStyle.Fill`. We subscribe to the panel_resize event:

```
private void panel_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Width > 500)
    {
        //increment the size of the form
        this.Height += 100;
    }
    else
    {
        // decrement the size of the form
        this.Height -= 100;
    }
}
```

The behavior is very strange, because we're trying to resize the form inside a resize operation. Is there any other way to simulate this behavior?

Comment: isn't it infinite loop? you're resizing panel with dock=fill, so your form resizes, but this triggers panel to resize and so on? I guess it would make sense if panel wasn't dock=fill, otherwise it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Adrian: It's not. It would be infinite loop if you do this in the Form_resize event. But in this case not.

Comment: I don't get it. How is a `Panel` set to `DockStyle.Fill` **ever** going to resize without its parent form being resized also? What you're asking to do doesn't make any sense, infinite loop or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to bypass the infinite loop by trying a token setting.

```
// at your custom panel level...
private Boolean AmIResizing = false

private void panel_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(AmIResizing)
      return;

    // set flag so it immediately gets out after first time started
    AmIResizing = true;

    // do your other resizing
    // The settings here will otherwise force your recursive form level resizing calls
    // but with your up-front check on the flag will get out.
    // then, when the form is done with it's stuff...


    // Now, clear the flag
    AmIResizing = false;

}
```